# Artalk XMPP: 'Authentication failed' message but credentials are valid

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xmpp

I set up an `Openfire` server (v4.6.6) and created a `test` user. I can login as the `test` user with both `Spark` (on Windows 10) and `Xabber` (on Android).

I'm trying to connect to the server with the [Artalk.Xmpp](https://github.com/araditc/Artalk.Xmpp):

```
using Artalk.Xmpp.Client;

var xmpp = new ArtalkXmppClient("143.#.#.133", "test@xmpp", "123", 5222, false);

try
{
    xmpp.Connect();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I get `"SaslException: SASL authentication failed."` error message but as I said the credentials are valid and I can connect with other clients. What is the problem here?

**Note 1**: I don't have a domain so I have to use the IP of the server.

**Note 2**: I tried with another library ([Sharp.Xmpp](https://github.com/pgstath/Sharp.Xmpp)) and got the same error.

Comment: Try using 'test' instead of 'test@xmpp' as username.

Comment: The error changes to: `Session establishment failed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by changing the Domain name to be exactly as the IP address of the server (previously I set it to be `xmpp`) and then using `test` instead of `test@xmpp` as username.